# Macros passed as arguments for randomizechoices does not work

Tags: macros, exam, random

This is a highly simplified version of a large work.

Please see the MWE given at the end. In the first case, when the macros are provided directly
as choices inside `randomizechoices` it works fine. However, when another macro is defined where the `randomizechoices` environment is inside the definition and the macro arguments are passed as choices, it produces the error message,

> ```
> Package exam-randomizechoices Warning: You need exactly one \CorrectChoice, I f
> ound 0 in question 1 on input line 40.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \erc@answer ->\@empty \CorrectChoice 
>                                      \A  
> l.38 \mcq{\A}{\B}{\C}{\D}
> ```

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{exam-randomizechoices}
\setrandomizerseed{2021}

\def\A{a}
\def\B{b}
\def\C{c}
\def\D{d}

% Define a macro for MCQ questions
\def\mcq#1#2#3#4{%
  Which one in this case?
  
  \begin{randomizechoices}
    \CorrectChoice#1
    \choice#2
    \choice#3
    \choice#4
  \end{randomizechoices}
}

\begin{document}

% Direct use of macro as choices
\begin{questions}
  \question Which one?

  \begin{randomizechoices}
    \CorrectChoice \A
    \choice \B
    \choice \C
    \choice \D
  \end{randomizechoices}
\end{questions}

% Choices are passed as macro arguments. This does not work.
\mcq{\A}{\B}{\C}{\D}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Believe it or not, it is a question of `%` at the end of lines.

I also added `\question` in the definition of `\mcq`.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{exam-randomizechoices}
\setrandomizerseed{2021}

\def\A{a}
\def\B{b}
\def\C{c}
\def\D{d}

% Define a macro for MCQ questions
\newcommand{\mcq}[4]{%
  \question Which one in this case?
  
  \begin{randomizechoices}
    \CorrectChoice#1% <---
    \choice#2% <---
    \choice#3% <---
    \choice#4% <---
  \end{randomizechoices}
}

\begin{document}

% Direct use of macro as choices
\begin{questions}
  \question Which one?

  \begin{randomizechoices}
    \CorrectChoice \A
    \choice \B
    \choice \C
    \choice \D
  \end{randomizechoices}

\mcq{\A}{\B}{\C}{\D}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is difficult to believe. Perhaps a bit more explanation on why this was the reason would make the answer more complete. And leaving out the `\question` part from the definition is intentional from my side for better (occasional) controls.

Comment: @Masroor I understand about `\question`, I added it in order to compile without warnings; since this is just a skeleton it should make little difference. Why the `%` solve the problem? Because `randomizechoices` doesn't define `\CorrectChoice`, but uses it just as a marker; and the substitution process it uses is quite rigid: the added spaces coming from the endlines confuse it.

Comment: Thanks. Please add the explanation lines to the answer. That would help others.